# WebFlux body serialization to runtime-dependent model?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, spring-webflux

When there is a `ClientResponse` from WebClient, in the simplest case we use
`clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyResponseModel.class)` to serialize the response body.

But it is not clear what is the way to go when responses' format can differ depending on situation.

For instance, when response could be one of the two types

```
type 1: {"a": <number>, "b": <string>}
type 2: {"c": <date>, "d": {"items": <array>}}
```

I suppose the basic algorithm should be like this

1. try to serialize to type 1
2. if OK return model of type 1
3. else try to serialize to type 2
4. if OK return model of type 2
5. else error of serialization

---

*What is the proper way to handle this serialization scenario with Spring WebFlux?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize the JSON response yourself. First get the response as json `String` and then do the deserialization yourself with the provided and configured Jackson `ObjectMapper` and if there is a `JsonMappingException` try it with model 2. This might not be as efficient as spring does it internally with `Jackson2JsonDecoder` as it processes the `InputStream` directly without creating a copy but this seems to be the only way to do it with the try/catch approach currently.

```
@RestController
class Controller {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public Controller(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/handler")
    public Mono<Object> getHandler() {
        return WebClient
            .create("https://baseurl.com")
            .get()
            .uri("/someUri")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(json ->
                Mono.<Object>fromCallable(() -> objectMapper.readValue(json, Model1.class))
                .onErrorResume(JsonMappingException.class, e ->
                        Mono.fromCallable(() -> objectMapper.readValue(json, Model2.class))
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to create a base class or interface for the response types and then implement a custom Jackson `JsonDeserializer` for it. This could detect which of the types should be used and then perform deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand what you are trying to do but would recommend you not to go down on this road. RESTful architectures have pros and cons, as everything else, and one of its benefits is ***observability***, the ability to clearly distinguish what is flowing into the wire. The other benefit you are going to forsake is **cacheability**.

The use of HTTP resources is paramount in RESTful APIs. It is dictated by
one of the REST Architectural constraints, namely **[Uniform interface](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/)**. It implies that your APIs are supposed to be resource-based and each resource in the system should have only one logical URI.

In your case, you have two different resources representations hence you should serve them through different URIs.

In the [Richardson Maturity Model](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), this is known as **Level 1**.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad you found the maturity model useful.